# Few F&Q before string firestore in python To develop a good database?

Tags: python, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have a few questions on firestore as my experience is with SQL and I want to shift on firestore for future.

1. Does firestore in python support offline as it support in android devices with or without its SDK?
2. Does it’s good to create multiple collection for multiple user i.e. 1 user to 1 collection and how does it affect my firestore plan?
3. Can there any libraries or pipeline to convert sql db to firestore?

Please suggest me a good library to use firestore whole feature in python!

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single question per post.

Answer (score 0):

1. Offline caching is only implemented in the client-side SDKs, which does not include Python. For server-side SDKs, such as the Python one, the logic is that the device should usually be connected to the internet, so it shouldn't need a cache.
2. ...
3. Firestore has a Python SDK, and it's included in the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart